# how to open a MS Word Document in client side by clicking on a link in my asp.net page and feed data to it

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, ms-word, word-automation

I want to open a MS Word Document in client side by clicking on a link in my asp.net page, then fill the document with some text from textboxes inside page, and after user has saved the document, I can get a response back to do my stuff with it.

what is your best solution to get it done?

As far as I researched, `OpenXML` is for manipulating a document on server, which doesn't suits my problem, I've got the same problem with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` which can create a word document but it is server side too and won't help.

I can create some xml template and use textboxes values to feed the xml with desired data using java script but the problem is, by using this approach the file just gets downloaded in client side and I have no idea whats going on then.
I need ms word to be open gets some data then close and inform me. Is this even possible?

Comment: Unsure what you're asking. In fact you _are manipulating a document_ because you want that document to be created on the fly based on some user provided data (via `TextBox` or somnething else)?

Comment: @EdSF Creating the document is not my problem, I can do this part via manipulating a xml file and some JavaScript but it will create a document which only can be downloaded, when user uses this doc I can't be informed. I want to provide a link, by clicking this link MS Word start working, and let the user do his/her work, but I want to be informed what changes were made inside the doc, and save changes in server after user has closed MS Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with using [DocX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/). After user provided some data inside page and submitting them, I create a document on server using this technology.
And the best way to update the document on server is using [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) features, it adds the exact functionality I need to my app. MS Office has built-in support for WebDAV and it can be easily configured inside IIS 7.5. So user can open/edit/save the document on server by using his/her own client MS Word and after saving, document on server gets updated.

Comment: Hi Nima, Any chance you can share the solution in detail of how you done that may be if some code can be provided, would be great help . Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try and put a VBA macro in the document to the Document_Close events.  Of course the user has to say the document is trusted to run the events as it is downloaded.

But in the Document_Close event you could read through that data that was filled in, assuming its isn fields or bookmarked and then  send that data back to the server.